# How to change color primary programmally

Tags: java, android, android-studio, colors

I would like to change the value of color primary dinamically, how can i do that? I'm using android Studio Java.
I tried in many ways but i don't know how to to that.
I'd like to change app tyle and changing the value of @color/Primary would be awesome but on the internet there aren't tutorials for this... I't's possible? If yes, how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme of your activity in your code:

myActivity.setTheme(R.style.my_theme);

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setTheme(int))

Comment: I tried to do it but it doesn't seem to work, I created a style with a ColorPrimary value that was different from the original, and I called it "Green". At this point I wrote in the code, after pressing a button I wrote "setTheme(R.style.Green)" but when I press nothing changes

Comment: No, it is not the way it works. You can set the theme on activity before setContentView, or specify it to a view constructor. If you want to change the color of the button based on its state (pressed,focused, etc) use Color State List (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource).